# ckeditor behaving strangely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm having all kinds of trouble getting CKEditor working in a Rails app.

1. It always makes a request for skin.js which doesn't even exist in the stock package.
2. Whether or not it displays the groups I specify seems completely up to chance. Some of them work (like Clipboard), others don't (Like Document).
3. All the icons are messed up. They display on the wrong buttons. Sometimes the same icon will show up on two separate buttons.

I have no idea what's going on. I didn't customize anything. I got the 4.4.0 download straight from the homepage. Standard package.

Any thoughts???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when it clashes with any other js script in the project. try downloading the code and run it in a separate project, if it works fine there , this means you have some other js in your code conflicting with the ckeditor script and usually this is the inline js which causes problem.